# Error while using cppunit

Tags: c++, cppunit

I am using cppunit for testing my project code. In my code in some places I have put some print statements for the debugging purpose like,

```
void TestSample()
{  
   //getting value from registry
   if( false == getvalue())
     printf("Error : Getting value form registry failed.");
   //.....
}
```

when I run this code I am getting anerror and the project is failing with an EXEC error.

```
 EXEC : Error : Getting value form registry failed.
```

Actually this is not an issue with the code. Its only with that print statement. When I replaced this `printf` its working fine. The only problem is the " Error : " keyword in the print statement.

How can I solve this issue? The print statement can't be removed. I think there will be an option in VS2010 for avoiding such an error. Help pls.

Comment: A little off-topic, but `if( false == getvalue() )` looks... unusual.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall its a so called Yoda condition. see http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html

Comment: @AndersK, nice one, I'll remember it xD

Comment: We are following this as our one of the coding std.:)

Comment: What is wrong with `if (!getValue())`?

Comment: I think you all peoples are concentrating only on the if condition. That's only a sample code. I am saying that the issue, which in found is with the "Error :" keyword in printf statement. The if contion if only a sample, as of now we can forget about the if condition .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer, that I want,

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsvc/archive/2012/02/29/output-from-exec-task-resulting-in-build-failure.aspx